# C mysql_num_rows() Segmentation fault

Tags: mysql, c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to execute MySQL query in C, however I get a Segmentation fault while calling mysql_num_rows().

Here's the code I'm using:

```
char *username = "test@mail.com";
char *password = "pass";

char query[1000];
int len;
char *q = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE `Email` = '%s' AND `Password` = '%s'";
len = snprintf(query, strlen(q) + strlen(username) + strlen(password), q, username, password);
MYSQL_RES *result;
if (db_query(query, result))
{
if (result != NULL)
{
    int test_count = mysql_num_rows(result);
    printf("%d\n", test_count);
}
}
else
{
printf("Query error\n");
}
```

And here is the db_query() function:

```
bool db_query(const char *query, MYSQL_RES *result)
{
    if (mysql_query(db_connection, query))
    {
     printf("mysql_query(): Error %u: %s\n", mysql_errno(db_connection), mysql_error(db_connection));

     return false;
    }

    if (!(result = mysql_store_result(db_connection)))
    {
    printf("mysql_store_result(): Error %u: %s\n", mysql_errno(db_connection), mysql_error(db_connection));

    return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I've tested the query and the problem isn't there, the connection is initiated too. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here, in the `db_query` function:

```
if (!(result = mysql_store_result(db_connection)))
```

The assignment to `result` has no visible effect in the function's caller - you're passing a pointer by value, changing the value of `result` in the callee doesn't do anything to `result` in the caller.

You need to change your function to take a pointer-to-pointer, and adapt the call site and the `db_query` function.

```
bool db_query(const char *query, MYSQL_RES **result)
{
  ...
  if (!(*result = mysql_store_result(db_connection)))
  ...
}
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! Seems like I always mess up the pointers lol. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Any changes to `result` in your `db_query` function are *not* reflected back to the caller, hence it will still contain the arbitrary value it had when it was created (as an auto variable with no initialisation.

If you want to change the value *and* have it reflected back, you should pass a double pointer to it then dereference the double pointer to get at the actual value.

Even better would be to return the `result` value and use its NULL/non-NULL status for a success code rather than returning `true/false`.